# use series to select rows from df pandas

Tags: pandas, boolean, selection, series, multiple-conditions

Continued from this thread: [get subsection of df based on multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726569/get-subsection-of-df-based-on-multiple-conditions)

I would like to pull given rows based on multiple conditions which are stored in a Series object.

```
columns = ['is_net', 'is_pct', 'is_mean', 'is_wgted', 'is_sum']
index = ['a','b','c','d']
data = [['True','True','False','False', 'False'],
       ['True','True','True','False', 'False'],
       ['True','True','False','False', 'True'],
       ['True','True','False','True', 'False']]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=index, data=data)
df

    is_net  is_pct  is_mean is_wgted    is_sum
a   True    True    False   False   False
b   True    True    True    False   False
c   True    True    False   False   True
d   True    True    False   True    False
```

My conditions:

```
d={'is_net': 'True', 'is_sum': 'True'}
s=pd.Series(d)
```

Expected output:

```
    is_net  is_pct  is_mean is_wgted    is_sum
c   True    True    False   False   True
```

My failed attempt:

```
(df == s).all(axis=1)


a    False
b    False
c    False
d    False
dtype: bool
```

Not sure why 'c' is False when the two conditions were met.

Note, I can achieve the desired results like this but I would rather use the Series method.

```
df[(df['is_net']=='True') & (df['is_sum']=='True')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you only have 2 conditions we can [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html#pandas.DataFrame.sum) these and filter the df:

```
In [55]:
df[(df == s).sum(axis=1) == 2]
​
Out[55]:
  is_net is_pct is_mean is_wgted is_sum
c   True   True   False    False   True
```

This works because booleans convert to `1` and `0` for `True` and `False`:

```
In [56]:
(df == s).sum(axis=1)
​
Out[56]:
a    1
b    1
c    2
d    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Would this work if there were more than 2 but less the len(df.columns) ?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain better you mean if you had more conditions but the total conditions are less than the number of columns? If so isn't this the same?

Comment: sorry yes, more than 2 conditions. Thats great, I'll try it out.

Comment: IIUC then if you had more conditions but you wanted any rows that matched at least 2 conditions then this would still work by changing to `>=2`

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could modify a little bit your solution by adding subset for your columns:

```
In [219]: df[(df == s)[['is_net', 'is_sum']].all(axis=1)]
Out[219]:
  is_net is_pct is_mean is_wgted is_sum
c   True   True   False    False   True
```

or:

```
In [219]: df[(df == s)[s.index].all(axis=1)]
Out[219]:
  is_net is_pct is_mean is_wgted is_sum
c   True   True   False    False   True
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort!